# How to trigger Javascript after the page loaded in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on a chrome extension ! Now my extension takes input from the user and then on click of a button it redirects to a page and fills the data entered in to a specific text field.
I am able to redirect to the page but when i try to get the element by using id name it gives null error ! as the javascript is running before the page is getting loaded properly. I tried but could not find a way !

In my content script i have this function :

```
function redirect(data)
{
location.replace("xyz.html");
        window.onload = function()
        {
            alert();
            var textField = document.getElementById("textField");
            textField.value = data ;
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `location.replace`, you are loading a new page, your current document will be closed which means you content script injected to this document won't work.

Say you are currently in page A and want to redirect to page B, one workaround would be when you get the data from A, save it to [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), then when redirected to B, get the data from `chrome.storage` or `persistent page`.

The sample code would look like:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("data", function(results) {
    var data = results.data;
    var textField = document.getElementById("textField");
    if (textField) {
        textField.value = data;
    } else {
        chrome.storage.local.set({"data": "your data here"});
        redirect("your data here");
    }
});

function redirect(data) {
    location.replace("xyz.html");
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand much !

Comment: @Ram, sample code added. I mean you could always try getting the data and textField, if textField is not undefined, that means you content script is running in the redirected page, then you could set the value of textField; otherwise, you are in the former page and just redirect it.

Comment: and how i can save it to the chrome storage ? You used chrome.storage.local.get but for this how to save first ? or should i just copy paste this ?

Comment: @Ram, just save it when there is no textField

Comment: hey mate ! i dont want to save anything from the current page. i want to redirect to a website the fill some data in the text field of that wesite !

Comment: @Ram, if you don't save the data in storage, background page or your server, how could you pass the data from one document to another document? The content script will be unloaded and loaded again when the page redirects.